# Can "singular form" be used with the phrase "individually for each"?

Tags: grammar

I found the sentence below on the Internet. I think this is written by natives.

> [Target achievement scores are set individually for each student](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=NL7kY6yTG0UC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22are%20set%20%20individually%20for%20each%22&source=bl&ots=qM67h0WYoO&sig=VAScG55AFKT10mPTW3eVn8I-bLo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22are%20set%20%20individually%20for%20each%22&f=false).

I would like to know whether the plural form "scores" is used to indicate there are multiple subjects such as math, science, etc. If there is only one subject, should this sentence be written as follows?

> The target achievement score is set individually for each student.

Comment: Your subject says "singular from" but your sentences don't include that phrase.  Did you mean *singular form*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either sentence works. The use of the plural in the first is OK because the sentence is about how target achievement scores are set in general: answer - individually for each student (of whom there are presumably more than one).
The meaning of the second sentence is clear but pursuing your logic I would start with "A" not "The" because the latter word suggests to the reader for a moment that there is only one such score. As we learn later in the sentence there is one per student.
But why not write:"Each student is set an individual target achievement score"?